# when will the lvalue of a thread.detach() function goes out of scope in the code below?

Tags: c++, multithreading

suppose I do the following :

```
void functionA(const char const input, int size)
{
   char* dummyData = new char[size] ;
   thread t(&functionB, dummyData);
   t.detach();

}

void functionB(const char* data)
{
   thread t2(&expendsiveFunction, data);
   t2.join();
}


void expendsiveFunction(const char* data)
{
    //do some expendsive stuff

   delete[] data;
}

void main()
{
   char* dataFromExternalSource;  //lets assume this was provided from by an external soruce receive via TCP
   functionA(dataFromExternalSource);

   //do other stuff
}
```

I want the main thread to be available to do other stuff while I let the detached thread do the hard labour, in this scenario,  am I right to say that dummyData will not go out of scope until  expendsiveFunction() finishes?

any advise/comment would be helpful.

question 2: so even if i dont use thread.join() in function B, thread t will terminate at the end of expendsiveFunction() if functionB() just calls expendsiveFunction() ? (if functionB is part of another class..)

Comment: The local variable `dummyData` goes out of scope when `functionA` returns. However, since you it points to dynamically allocated memory, that memory will persist (until you call `delete[]`)

Comment: `functionB` is leaking `data` (aka the memory for `dummyData`) since it is not calling `delete[] data` after `expendsiveFunction()` exits. But why is `functionB()` (which is already running in a thread), creating yet another thread just to wait on it?  That is a waste of a thread. It should be calling `expendsiveFunction()` directly, eg: `void functionB(const char* data) { expendsiveFunction(data); delete[] data; }`.  Or even better: `void functionB(const char* data) { std::unique_ptr<char[]> deleter(data); expendsiveFunction(data); }`

Comment: `data = NULL` is useless; Note that `data` in `expensiveFunction` is a different variable than `data` in `functionB`, and assigning `data=NULL` in `expensiveFunction` will not alter anything in `functionB`.

Comment: so delete[] will do ?

Comment: yes. Note that - in contrast to other languages - C++ does not have any garbage collector; so there is no need to set variables to `NULL` once the memory is freed using `delete`. You can, but it has no effect other than the variable then points to `NULL`.

Comment: just to be sure the detach thread will be std::terminate at the end of expendsiveFunction() ?


@Remy Lebeau:
the reason of starting a thread in another thread is because functionA and B are from different classes... I want to pass the data from one class to another before it goes out of scope..

Comment: `dummyData` is not the 'lvalue of a `thread.detach()` function'. It is a constructor argument. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please elaborate on what i'm doing wrong ? I dont get the "dont mis-use standard terminology" part.

Comment: @angelhalo: "*just to be sure the detach thread will be std::terminate at the end of expendsiveFunction() ?*" - I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. But a thread ends when its entry function exits. The thread started by `functionA()` will end when `functionB()` exits. The thread started by `functionB` will end when `expendsiveFunction()` exits.

Comment: @angelhalo: "*the reason of starting a thread in another thread is because functionA and B are from different classes... I want to pass the data from one class to another before it goes out of scope.*" - that does not require starting a new thread. And if you are worried about the lifetime of a given piece of data across threads, you should use `std::shared_ptr` to manage that for you.

Comment: Hi Remy thanks for the tips.. I had the misconception in the past where if the function in the thread calls another function which calls another functions (like functionA->functionB->expendsiveFunction , i need to split twice to make sure its not using the main's resources)...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are not right, since local variable `dummyData` goes out of scope when `functionA` finishes, and `functionA` will not wait for any other function or thread to finish.

The memory to which `dummyData` points, however, will remain valid since you allocate it dynamically using `new[]`. This memory is on the heap, and it will never "go out of scope" as it will never be popped from the stack; it will remain valid until you call `delete[]` somewhere in your code.

Note that only `functionB` and `expensiveFunction` hold a reference to this memory, so these functions are the only ones which can free this memory; if they don't, then you will have a memory leak.

BTW: your code does not compile; but that's not the question here.

Comment: my bad on forgetting to delete[] at the end of expendsiveFunction ...

yes thats the intenion of using new before the thread detaches...is this a good way of preserving the data? if I wish to pass data from function to function for a detach thread?  ( i want to avoid using global variables)